# Is it possible to have non-linear relationship between temperature scales?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, thermal-conductivity, metrology

Is it possible to have a hypothetical temperature scale that does not follow a linear relationship with another temperature scale? For example, the graph formed between the readings taken by a thermometer in Fahrenheit and Celsius is a straight line.

Comment: Yes but such a scale won't be proportional to the average kinetic energy

Comment: For very specific purposes one could think of using different quantities that have similar function. In chemical systems reaction rates often depend exponentially on temperature, so one could imagine using the logarithm of temperature for that application. I don't think I have seen it in practice, though. Using the logarithm of concentrations (of protons) is very common, though: it's the pH scale.

Comment: Statistical physicists often suggest the [thermodynamic $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta) $=1/kT$ as better scale.

Comment: As the answers below explain, sure you can. But what is the reason for the question?

Answer (score 4):

You can define a scale however you want, but it wouldn't be particularly useful or meaningful. You could define a new temperature scale as "Kelvin squared" which obviously would be non-linear in its relationship with Kelvin. But it wouldn't have the usual desirable properties of a temperature scale, for example, on this scale, a fixed temperature change results in variable changes in atomic kinetic energy, depending on the actual temperature.

All commonly used temperature scales are linear with respect to one another. It is very useful to have a fixed relationship between temperature change and energy change. You could invent a non-linear scale, but I struggle to think of practical general applications.

Answer (score 4):

In my lab, we prepare samples by annealing them at various temperatures using a resistive heater. Essentially, we have a thin tungsten filament which is enclosed within small ceramic cylinders, not unlike a jump rope:

[image]

The sample sits on these cylinders. When we apply a voltage across the filament, current starts to flow and everything heats up.

---

The relationship between the voltage $V$ which we apply to the filament and the temperature $T$ which the sample reaches is highly nonlinear, because it involves balancing the thermal power $V \cdot I(V)$ being supplied to the sample stage against the rate at which energy is lost via conduction (the sample stage is touching the rest of the chamber) and radiation ($\propto T^4-T_0^4$, where $T_0$ is the ambient temperature).  Making some very crude approximations, we might find that $V \propto T^2$, but the true relationship is much more complex.

The point is that we use $V$ as a temperature scale. I might say "I heated the sample at 8V for 2 hours," for example. That may be meaningless to anybody outside of my lab group, but that's not important - it remains a useful in-house temperature scale which is related very non-linearly with $K$ or $^\circ C$.

Answer (score 0):

[Thermodynamic beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta) is the reciprocal of the usual temperature (a nonlinear relationship), and it is arguably [more natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta#Advantages)  than the usual temperature scale.